# Объединить несколько похожих классов в один абстрактный

Tags: java, ооп, разработка-игр

Написал я игру, показал преподавателю, он мне посоветовал объединить все классы типа "враги" (всех enemy) в один абстрактный.

Объясните зачем это нужно, если все итак хорошо?

Comment: Все связанное с вопросом, должно быть в вопросе, а не ссылки на сторонние ресурсы..........В целом, вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. [См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

## Чтобы уменьшить дублирование кода и его общий объём

По всей видимости, преподаватель углядел в вашем коде много одинаковых фрагментов и предложил вынести повторяющиеся части в отдельное место. Вынесение в абстрактный класс это достаточно типичный в ООП-шных языках способ это сделать. Не универсальный, но встречающийся более-менее везде.

В программировании это стремление известно, как DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself, не повторяйтесь). Этим достигается несколько приятных моментов:

- Объём кода становится меньше, шансов наделать в нём ошибок меньше.
- Внесение изменений в этот повторяющийся фрагмент кода если потребуется, то скорее всего везде. И проще сделать это в одном месте, чем во всех классах по отдельности. Опять же, снижается вероятность наделать ошибок.

### Но делать это надо осторожно

Легко привыкнуть к тому, что "вынести повторяющийся код в класс" это всегда хорошая идея.

**Но это не так.** И с таким подходом легко воткнуться в ситуацию, когда в каком-то одном случае вам реализация абстрактного класса самую малость не подходит, т. к. вынесенная в него "общая часть" в нём немножко отличается. Хорошо, если вы можете сделать `override` нужного метода (хотя нет, не очень хорошо, см. далее), но ситуация взрывается, если вы вынуждены сделать другой, очень похожий класс.

А затем, следуя принципу "вынесения общих частей в отдельный класс" вы заводите ещё один уровень иерархии и код становится гораздо сложнее, чем необходимо. Проблема вроде решена, но код начинает напоминать дремучий тёмный лес.

Где ошибка? В абстракции. Порой выносить нужно *не все* общие части, немного дублирования можно оставлять, если это видится специфичной для конкретного наследника деталью, и наследники без неё возможны.

> #### ["duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction"](https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction?duplication)
>
> #### *"с дублированием жить гораздо легче, чем с кривой абстракцией"*

Comment: Здорово, что в ответе указаны не только достоинства, но и недостатки подхода.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно это для того, чтобы Ваш код соответствовал принципам ООП.

Зачем нужно ООП? – вопрос очень объемный, можете почитать об этом, например, [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148015/).

По поводу абстрактного класса безотносительный пример:

Есть два класса: `Cat` и `Dog`, в каждом из которых есть поле для имени животного и некий метод `makeNoise()` (это у Вас есть сейчас):

```
public class Cat {
    private String mName;

    public Cat(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dog {
    private String mName;

    public Dog(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

Можно определить абстрактный класс `Animal` и его сабклассы `Cat` и `Dog` (это Вам предлагают сделать):

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private String mName;

    public Animal(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public abstract void makeNoise();
}
```

---

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

    public Cat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

Абстрактный класс задает некоторую структуру его сабклассов: и кошка и собака могут произносить звуки (в суперклассе определен абстрактный метод `makeNoise()`), но произносят они разные звуки (в каждом из сабклассов используется своя реализация метода `makeNoise()`).

Comment: Вы понимаете, что вы как фрилансер сейчас выступаете? Только оплату не просите. Потому, что отвечаете на вопросы, которые должны быть закрыты, как минимум до тех пор, пока не будут отредактированы в соответствии с правилами ресурса. Вы побуждаете таких пользователей и дальше задавать вопросы не соответствующие правилам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Нет, не понимаю. В моем понимании, я не выступаю в роли фрилансера (это же очевидно, черт возьми). А причиной того, почему ТС не разместил код в вопросе, очевидно является то, что этого самого кода там довольно много.

Comment: это проблемы ТС. Он должен предоставить минимальный пример. Описать суть проблемы. Если У него 1000 классов и 10000 строк кода - это он должен смотреть и вытаскивать то, что нужно..... И суть ресурса в накоплении опыта и базы знаний для всех, для многих. То есть вопрос должен находиться из поисковиков и люди с аналогичными проблемами приходить и видеть как решать эту проблему. И это явно не то, что написано в вопросе. Явно ответ не поможет никому, кроме ТС. Поэтому вы свободно можете также и по скайпу помочь - смысл не изменится. А так только мусор плодите

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я согласен, что вопрос мог бы быть полнее. Но ответ вполне даёт представление о том, по какому принципу из нескольких похожих классов можно выделить абстрактный родительский класс.

Comment: post_zeew спасибооо у меня тож с абстрактами не очень было)))но теперь стало яснее)зачем писать каждому если можно задать в ондном))))))))